# My sun light isn't rendering in EEVEE. how do I fix?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image: VIEWPORT IMAGE - This is what it should look like.]

[[image: RENDERED IMAGE - This is what renders though?2]

The top image is the viewport view, that's how it *should* look. The bottom image is the rendered view :/

I am not new to Blender, yet I have no clue what's going on. "Scene Lights" are turned on. The Sun says it's enabled in the render view, and I don't have any hidden objects blocking the sun. Any ideas what is happening? Every other light type works. I tested a bright purple point light, area light, and spot light all right in the center of the ship and they were visible, but the sun light still didn't work.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Or the very least you could do is show the whole viewport in _Solid_ shading (or maybe _Wireframe_?) so that all objects - especially the sun object - are visible... and the settings of the sun would be helpful, too. Maybe even _Render Properties_. Because simply showing two renders gives us no information on what you have actually done in your scene. To the bottom left of the render view there is some bright spot in the water which is not there in the viewport, that's an indicator your sun could be there, just not shining the way you expect it.